# Why doesn't Xcode recognize -ignoreTouch:forEvent: in UITapGestureRecognizer subclass?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uikit, uitapgesturerecognizer

According to [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer) there is a method `-ignoreTouch:forEvent:`. I need to mimic a `-pointInside:withEvent:` functionality to make it handle taps only specific shape.

But when I try call this method Xcode doesn't know it. No autocompletion and it gives error for undeclared method. But documentation clearly says we can call ignoreTouch:forEvent: on UITapGestureRecognizer to ignore a touch.

Edit: Documentation says there is a class extension for it but I cant import this either. Not found: `#import "UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h"`

Answer (score 2):

It's part of `UIKit` so import it like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems when I do this it works:

```
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>
@implementation OFShapeTapGestureRecognizer
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //[self ignoreTouch:[touches anyObject] forEvent:event];
    // ... here, fancy logic.
    if (ignore) {
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled;
    }
}
```